# Authentication error

Tags: aaa, cisco-3750

I have set the username **** privilege 5 secret **** & applied aaa via console. now unable to access switch through console.
 After entering enable showing authentication error.

can someone help me to resolve the issue.

Configuration:

config for console:

```
username cisco privilege 5 secret cisco 
line vty 0 4 login local 
end
```

config for aaa

```
aaa new-model 
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local 
aaa authentication enable default group tacacs+ enable 
aaa authorization commands 1 default group tacacs+ local 
aaa authorization commands 15 default group tacacs+ local 
aaa accounting exec default start-stop group tacacs+ 
aaa accounting commands 1 default start-stop group tacacs+ 
aaa accounting commands 15 default start-stop group tacacs+
```

aaa accounting network default start-stop group tacacs+

Comment: Please upload the AAA commands in your running-config, your privilege/authentication commands, and the config on your console port.

Without that we can only guess.

Comment: config for console
username cisco privilege 5 secret cisco
line vty 0 4
login local
end

config for aaa
aaa new-model
aaa authentication login default group tacacs+ local
aaa authentication enable default group tacacs+ enable
aaa authorization commands 1 default group tacacs+ local 
aaa authorization commands 15 default group tacacs+ local 
aaa accounting exec default start-stop group tacacs+
aaa accounting commands 1 default start-stop group tacacs+
aaa accounting commands 15 default start-stop group tacacs+
aaa accounting network default start-stop group tacacs+

Comment: When you login via console are you using a AAA username or the local username?

Comment: local username as switch is not connected to live environment. so unable to use tacas username. Also want to mentioned that I have not applied Tacas server ip

Comment: you need to ensure the command "login local" in on line con 0.
Right now you appear to only have it on your VTY lines.

Comment: but im unable to take console to do the changes..any other way to do config for it

Comment: You will need to bypass the password just as if you were doing a password recovery. 

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-2950-series-switches/12040-pswdrec-2900xl.html

This will get you into the switch.

Comment: @ZackScaringello, you should create an answer so that others can learn from this too.

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing your configuration it appears that you applied **login local** only the VTY lines and not the console port.

Since you no longer have access to the device you will need to initate a password recovery for the device following the instructions listed [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-2950-series-switches/12040-pswdrec-2900xl.html).  This will allow you to log into the device and make changes.

You will then need to add the following configurations:

**line con 0**

**login local**

Once that has been added you should be able to login via the console port using a locally created account.

Two more small pieces of advice:

1. Don't use Cisco as your username.  Always create a unique username for your organization.  This adds a small layer of obscurity to your security posture.
2. Don't forget to perform a **copy run start** after you apply **login local** to your console port.  You don't want to reboot later on and realize that you can no longer console in.

Comment: hi Zack, my issue is resolved now.. I have applied privileged 5 for username & password.so, I had only read only access..i have reset the switch